# MongoDB not dropping duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to ensure an index in mongoDB and drop all duplicates, but it just doesnt work. I am using the node.js native mongo driver module.

```
var suggestions = db.collection('suggestions');

suggestions.dropIndex("lower");
suggestions.ensureIndex({lower: 1}, { unique: true, dropDups: true }, function(err, docs){

    console.log( docs );

});
```

the console logs: "lower_1"

the documents look like:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54e9b2c2fe9a402c0e71adad"
},
"name": "Two door cinema club",
"weight": 0,
"lower": "two door cinema club",
"type": "performer"
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54ccd65cb12c85540bbfe578"
},
"name": "Two door cinema club",
"weight": 0,
"lower": "two door cinema club",
"type": "performer"
}
```

there are no errors, and the duplicates documents remain in the collection. Am I missing something? I can read and write to the collection, so I know the connection to the DB is ok.

Comment: Could you show the documents in your database that are duplicate? So another record with the same "lower" value?

Comment: Try dopping it like this: suggestions.dropIndex({lower: 1}) before setting it again. It might still have the old index.

Comment: What do you see when you run `db.suggestions.getIndexes();`?

Comment: Works fine for me in 2.6.6. Can you write a complete script demonstrating the problem?

Comment: can u tell your mongo version?